# control incoming word in socketserver

Tags: python, python-2.7, socketserver

hi this is my program in python

```
#!usr/bin/python
import SocketServer

class Echohandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        print "Got Connection form :",self.client_address
        while True:
            data = self.request.recv(1024)
            if data == "hi":
                self.request.send("HI there!")

serveradder = ("0.0.0.0",9002)
SocketServer.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
server = SocketServer.TCPServer(serveradder,Echohandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

when i connect to the server and send hi server just return hi and not send HI there!
how can i solve this problem?!

Comment: I use data = str(data) before if statment but not work

Comment: i use the nc to connect to the server!

Answer (score 0):

the answer is self.data!

```
#!usr/bin/python
import SocketServer

class Echohandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        print "Got Connection form :",self.client_address
        while True:
            data = ''
            self.data = self.request.recv(1024)
            data = self.data
            #self.request.send(data)
            if str(data).strip() == 'hi' :
                self.request.send("HI there!")

serveradder = ("127.0.0.1",9002)
SocketServer.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
server = SocketServer.TCPServer(serveradder,Echohandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score -2):

you must first strip the data !

```
#!usr/bin/python
import SocketServer

class Echohandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        print "Got Connection form :",self.client_address
        while True:
            data = self.request.recv(1024)
            if str(data).strip() == "hi":
                self.request.send("HI there!")

serveradder = ("0.0.0.0",9002)
SocketServer.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
server = SocketServer.TCPServer(serveradder,Echohandler)
server.serve_forever()`
```

Comment: Could you please add more details and explanation on what was the problem? Thanks.